# C# String to RTF Performance

Tags: c#, string, performance, rtf

i have got some performance problems about an conversion from string to RTF. My method looks like this:

```
static string convert_to_plain(string rtf)
{
      RichTextBox temp = new RichTextBox();
      temp.Rtf = rtf;
      return temp.Text;
}
```

Bt it seems my method is to slow i am losing about 3 seconds if i am using this method. I thought about using an String-Builder or something but i don't think it will help. By the way i already tried to initialize the RTF-Object only one time at program-start but this changed nothing.

So have anyone an idear how to imrove the performance of the method?

Thank you!
Best regards
Teyhouse

Comment: You could write an rtf parser that simply drops all control codes and groups, just performing character unescaping? That doesn't feel like a huge thing...

Comment: you want to convert rtf to plain text?

Comment: Right, i am converting RTF to PlainText in case of some preview in a table...

Answer (score 0):

is this library faster?
this has many different functions, perhaps you can use it

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C

Comment: Thanks, my solution was to convert only the first 600 chars because i was using it for some preview in a listview... so that's my solution :)  If i got some time i will try the Lib from above thanks!